# event handler does not work for inherited control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I have a class that inherits from ComboBox. If I use the standard ComboBox class in my control the following event handler works fine:

```
private void SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

If I change the type to MyComboBox, starting the app fails with the following message:

**Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.**

Now I need to change the signature to

```
SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

What gives?

EDIT: some example code...

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication2="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="wpfApplication2:MyComboBox">
                    <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="SelectionChanged" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <wpfApplication2:MyComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,145,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**MyComboBox.cs:**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: As usual on this website, you need to create a [small but complete working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.